# Heroku deployment: embedded jetty port

Tags: heroku, port, embedded-jetty

I am deploying an embedded jetty app on Heroku and it listens on port 80 for http.  However, on startup I read the System.getenv("PORT") value and initialize the jetty server using that port value, like so:

```
    if (isproduction) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "System.getenv(\"PORT\"):{0}", System.getenv("PORT"));
        port = Integer.valueOf(System.getenv("PORT"));
        baseurl = "http://xxxx-xxxx.herokuapp.com";
    }

    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Starting jetty on port: {0}", port);
    final Server jettyServer = new Server(port);
    jettyServer.setHandler(context);
```

The above prints

```
2017-05-25T17:34:02.943531+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: System.getenv("PORT"):45203
2017-05-25T17:34:02.945234+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Starting jetty on port: 45203
```

However, `heroku open` from the command line opens the application at port 80.  This is not really a problem (the application is fully operational) but it is unexpected behavior. Anyone can shed some light as to whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [its](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-apps/blob/c402fef1efc02a350f370eab48be06dcd8475663/commands/apps/open.js#L9) [code](https://github.com/heroku/legacy-cli/blob/d7e9718079b9936ffd264529bdd03a6734fd64cc/lib/heroku/command/apps.rb#L232), `heroku open` does not support custom ports.

Comment: well, ok but the thing is, mine is not a custom port.  System.getenv("PORT") is an environment variable set by Heroku at startup.  Also, the question is why the app listens to port 80 when the jetty server is started using a different port

Comment: What do you mean listens on 80? How do you tell?

Comment: I open a browser and visit the welcome page of the deployed jetty site on heroku

Comment: @chrisl08 I don't know why it listens on 80, the question was about `heroku open` which does not support setting any ports at all. No matter if it's an env variable or not.